# Unable to run top command using jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I am unable to run top command using JSch. Please see following code:

```
Session session = null;
    ChannelShell channel = null;
    PipedInputStream pipeIn = null;
    PipedOutputStream pipeOut = null;
    String response = "";
    try {
        session = getSession(hostIp, userName, password);
        channel = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel( "shell" );
        pipeIn = new PipedInputStream();
        pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream( pipeIn );
        channel.setInputStream(pipeIn);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
        channel.connect(3*1000);
        pipeOut.write(command.getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(3*1000);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (pipeIn != null) pipeIn.close();
        if (pipeOut != null) pipeOut.close();
        closeResources(session, channel);
    }
```

Since top is an interactive command I have used ChannelShell. The above code shows the output up to top command but it not showing any response of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the value that you're assigning to the `command` variable, but when I assign `"top\n"` to it and then run your code, I can see the output. Are you maybe missing the newline after the command? You may also have to flush the `pipeOut` stream after writing to it, although that was not necessary in my tests.