# Java and SSH looking to execute multiple commands from a file, across a list of hosts in another file and write the output to a file

Tags: java, ssh

“my-thoughts” Provided the code below. but it’s not working 100%. 1) if I have more than one command, the program won’t run. 2) one command in the command file, the script won’t execute properly. for example with “ls” the log file will have the following "Last login: Tue Jun 9 14:30:11 2015 from localhost lsmyhost:~ myaccount$ ls "

JSSH class:

```
public class JSSH {
    private static final String user = "UID"; 
    private static final String password = "pass";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException,
        InterruptedException, IOException {

        JSSH jssh = new JSSH();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        for (String host : jssh.listOfhost()) {
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(getProperties());
            session.connect(10 * 1000);
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

            for(String command : jssh.listOfCommand()) {
                channel.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes()));
                channel.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUT_FILE)));
                channel.connect(15 * 1000);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        return properties;
    }

    private List<String> listOfCommand() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder("command_file.txt").build();
    }

    private List<String> listOfhost() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder("host_file.txt").build();
    }
}
```

LineBuilder Class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LineBuilder {

    private String fileName;

    public LineBuilder(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public List<String> build() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your LineBuilder class can be replaced with Java's [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) method.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the new java 7 function, but why am I having an issue? I tested printing each line, and it works. I believe my issue is between these 2 lines                                          channel.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes()));
                channel.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUT_FILE)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `new FileOutputStream`, you are *overwriting* the file.  So you definitely should not be calling it for every command, as that would result in a file which contains only the output of the last command executed.

A FileOutputStream should almost always be wrapped in a BufferedOutputStream, as it often improves performance.  This has been true for a very long time, since before Java even existed.

I'm guessing you want the output from all commands on all hosts to be in that log file.  If that's the case, you want to create the OutputStream *once*, outside of any loops.

You probably should not create a new connection for every command.  Move these two lines outside of your inner for-loop, so they're right after the creation of the Channel:

```
channel.setOutputStream(outputStream);
channel.connect(15 * 1000);
```

Note that the [documentation for setOutputStream](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#setOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29) states that you should be calling it before you call Channel.connect().  Also, since we're using a single OutputStream for all commands from all hosts, you want to pass `true` as the second argument, so JSch won't close that OutputStream.

In fact, the [documentation for setInputStream](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#setInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) says the same thing:  It has to be called before calling connect().

So how does one manage that?  You'll need to create a background Thread that "feeds" lines to the InputStream through a pipe.  This is accomplished with PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream, which allow one thread to read from a stream fed by another thread.

So, the revised version might look like this:

```
JSSH jssh = new JSSH();
final String[] commands = jssh.listOfCommand();

// Local class for feeding commands to a pipe in a background thread.
class CommandSender
implements Runnable {
    private final OutputStream target;

    IOException exception;

    CommandSender(OutputStream target) {
        this.target = Objects.requireNonNull(target);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (String command : commands) {
                target.write(command.getBytes());
                target.write(10);   // newline
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception = e;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted, exiting prematurely.");
        }
    }
}

try (OutputStream log = new BufferedOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE))) {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    for (String host : jssh.listOfhost()) {
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(getProperties());
        session.connect(10 * 1000);

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setOutputStream(log, true);

        try (PipedInputStream commandSource = new PipedInputStream();
             OutputStream commandSink = new PipedOutputStream(commandSource)) {

            CommandSender sender = new CommandSender(commandSink);
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(sender);
            sendThread.start();

            channel.setInputStream(commandSource);
            channel.connect(15 * 1000);

            sendThread.join();
            if (sender.exception != null) {
                throw sender.exception;
            }
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

A word of caution:  Calling String.getBytes() converts the String's characters to bytes using the platform's default charset.  In Windows, this is usually UTF16-LE (two bytes per character), so if you are making ssh connections from Windows to Unix or Linux machines, which typically expect characters encoded in UTF-8, you may get a lot of failures.  The easy solution is to specify an explicit charset, assuming you know the charset used by the target machines:

```
command.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: Thanks VGR for your detail explenation, but can you please provide how the full code will look like so I can be able to digest it.  I am getting a lot of errors trying to plug in your recommendation into what I have. Thanks again!

Comment: I have Java 7, can you take a look at the code below and let me know if it's correct or not.   https://github.com/mamet777/SSH_JSCH/wiki

Comment: I had two errors in the code:  `Iterable<String>` should have been `String[]` and the type of commandSource needed to be `PipedInputStream`.  Answer updated accordingly.  Make sure you add import statements for the various java.io classes and for java.util.Objects.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much again for your detailed explanation!! One more question if you don't mind. how can I change properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); to allow me to accept the new keys to be added to the known_host file. JSCH http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html  has a working example  that prompts me to add new keys to the known_host file if it's not there, but i am not sure which part of the script handles that. I am really looking to get that done for security purposes. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That is complex enough that it should probably be submitted as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `shell` channel and sending raw command data (i.e., a `ByteArrayInputStream` in your case) you need to make sure to include a newline character `\n` after each command. Otherwise, the command will not execute, but just sit and wait for more input.

See my response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502471/unable-to-run-top-command-using-jsch/) for a similar example.

Comment: I am not sure if ByteArray is the correct way or not, I am only checking on few configuration. for ex Ifconfig. even with \n, if I have more than one command I get Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request. do you have a full example? please!